# What do I need to look for in a KVM that connects to many different devices?

Tags: kvm-switch

I've used several KVMs in the past, and they've all had the same flaw: they work great if you leave the same two machines connected, but if you need to connect/disconnect lots of machines to the same KVM port the KVM will just stop working after a few weeks, so that a new machine won't be able to use the keyboard/mouse. The monitor will continue to work fine, and switch to where it needs to, but most computers just won't detect the keyboard or mouse anymore.

The exact situation is this: I have a workbench that I use to fix broken computers. The bench has two permanent stations that support two computers each. Each station has a monitor, keyboard, and mouse connected to a KVM. When a broken or malfunction computer comes into my office, I'll set it in one of the four position and connect the KVM cables from that position. There could be a different machine on each KVM position every day.

Right now, this just doesn't work. I end up bringing extra keyboards/mice over to use these computers, and this just doesn't work as well. I need a KVM that will continue to work even after connecting/disconnecting a number of different computers.

*What do I need to look for to find a KVM that will do this successfully over a long period?*

Again: most any KVM will work if you never or rarely change machines, or for the first few weeks even if you do change often. Even the KVMs I have now would still work if I were to put them somewhere that the computers sharing the station never changed. The problem is just that I have different (sometimes no) computers connected all the time. How can I find one that will continue to work long term?

Note that I'm not looking for a shopping suggestion or specific product: I'm looking the *technical feature* I need to be aware of that will allow my own product search to be effective.

Comment: Have you tried / tested IP KVMs?  If the issue is cable / connector wear, that could reduce the problem / make it possible to push the problem out to the cheaper part (the device at the computer end)

Comment: Or perhaps get some extension cables so you don't unplug devices from the KVM itself ?

Comment: @Lawrence that completely missing the point. The machines we connect/disconnect come in from completely different buildings.

Comment: @Slartibartfast that idea has appeal, as we could then even do more work from our desks, rather than needing to visit the machines in person, but so far cost has been the barrier. And many of these machines don't support that kind of management, such that we'd still need kvm cables connected to a physical IP-KVM unit.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I must be. I don't connect machines to KVMs, I connect cables to KVMs, so unless I have your setup imagined incorrectly, I don't know how you're connecting machines to KVMs without cables